# IF statement that will let me input values from a single cell

Tags: excel

I need to look through column C and search for a text "TF06" and if that's true I need to replace the corresponding row in column D to the specific input FROM cell F2.

This is as far as I can get. Here is my code:

```
=IF((VLOOKUP("TF06", C2:D54, 2, FALSE)), REPLACE(ROWS(VLOOKUP("TF06", C2:D54, 2, FALSE)), 1, 1, F2), 0)
```

Comment: Please edit your Question Title to make it more human-eye friendly. Thank you. :-)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Please do not make your title all caps

Comment: Wait.  If you are replacing each row value with input from cell F2 then VLOOKUP is not what you want.  You want to make a formula that checks the adjacent cell for "TF06" and the formula should just return F2 when it finds it

Answer (score 0):

This should work...if its always F2 change it to F$2 this should be in column D if thats where you want the data to go?

```
=IF(A3="tf06",F3,"")
```

Comment: Should add it leaves D blank if there's no match